# multiline Text box property android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've a `multiline text box` in my app and i want to set a **fixed character length** so that in one line not more than of that characters appear how to do this?

say if maxlegnth is 150 for textbox then maxlength for single line is to set 50.   **MAX LENGTH FOR EACH LINE**

Comment: Is that works or not? Let me know please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) elements, or any subclsses of TextView(such as EditText), you can manage this with [setFilters()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFilters%28android.text.InputFilter%5B%5D%29).

What you need to do is to create a class implementing InputFilter, for example

```
public class MyTestFilter implements InputFilter {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        // do you checks, and only return what you wish to have replaced
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then use

```
youEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MyTestFilter()});
```